# Custom delimiter that needs to be processed and loaded into hive

Tags: file, hadoop, hive, delimiter

I have a log file delimited by |~ and also the values are enclosed in double quotes . I tried loading the file into hive using the following . But i didnt succeed.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AUDIT_DETAIL 
(
  EVENT_ID string
, DETAIL_ID smallint
, SERVER_CUID String
, DETAIL_TYPE_ID smallint
, DETAIL_TEXT String 
, START_TIMESTAMP DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE 
) row format delimited fields terminated by '|~'
location '/user/Audit_Detail';

Is there any way to accomplish this other than hive udf?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter you are using is a multicharacter delimiter which is not supported till ver 0.13 . It might be the reason for your error.

refer : [How can I do a double delimiter(||) in Hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484015/how-can-i-do-a-double-delimiter-in-hive/25485717#25485717)

Comment: @K S Nidhin, I tried and i get an error that " error while compiling statement: failed: parseexception line 10:1 cannot recognize input near 'serde' ''org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.lazysimpleserde'' 'with' in serde properties specification "

This was my ddl,
CREATE ..ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054' SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim'='|~')
 stored as textfile;

If i run without DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054' , i am not getting any error , but the data was not loaded properly